# .htaccess file not rewriting URL's correctly when project is in subdirectory

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

I currently have a problem with rewriting my URL's using the .htaccess file when a Laravel project is in a subdirectory.

usually when not in subdirectory having /vacancies -> /index.php/vacancies using this below .htcaccess file works.

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Though now the project exists within a subdirectory I require the URL to be re written as so /vacancies -> /abc/index.php/vacancies.

The home page works correctly though any links just return a not found error.

What changes would I need to have the .htaccess file do this for me.

so on investigating further upon entering 'index.php' into the url itself the page loads correctly if this helps anymore with answering the question.

Thanks!

Comment: add `RewriteBase /abc/` after `RewriteEngine on`, hope this will help

Comment: sadly this doesn't seem to have worked, it still comes up with a not found error. If i were to write into the url `/abc/index.php/vacancies`. The exact error message is  *The requested URL `/abc/vacancies` was not found on this server.*

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't modify the default `.htaccess` provided in a Laravel app. You need to use Apache's directory alias in the virtual host config file for your site. You need to have the following format:

```
#Change the paths accordingly
Alias /vacancies /path/to/app/public

<Directory /path/to/app/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted #If using Apache 2.4 add this.
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this thank you for your suggestions, This turned out to be a problem with the virtual host file and where the project was created as I have soft links let up to direct apache.

As such Apache was looking in the actual project location set in the virtual hosts file rather than the soft link one intended causing the not found issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check of .ht* permissions in the apache httpd config file if you are using apache. I had the same problem and I had permissions denied problem for .htaccess file. If you are on shared host, try to contact hosting support.

Comment: I am indeed using apache, what permissions should I be looking for exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Tried putting it on top of the htaccess file ? Helps for me in some kind of cases, seems weird but it does.

Comment: Hi what do you mean "on top" as in put it in a directory below?

Comment: I mean inside of the .htaccess file itself. The content of the file, u can shift stuff from top to bottom etc, it helps for me in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I notice fro your answer you've managed to "fix" this. However, you have some fundamental errors in the `.htaccess` file you posted, so I'm not sure how this is working exactly?

> ```
> RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
> RewriteLogLevel 3
> ```

These two directives are not valid in `.htaccess` files and consequently will result in a 500 Internal Server Error. These can only be used directly in the server config or virtual host context. These are also Apache 2.2 directives, so won't work on Apache 2.4.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^index.php [L]
> ```

(Part of the "front-controller"). You are missing a *space* between the first and second arguments, so this will fail to rewrite any requests to `index.php` - your "front-controller". (Maybe this is just a typo, but it's difficult to see a typo like this could creep in?) For example, this should be more like:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

> ```
> # Handle Authorization Header
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
> RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
> ```

These directives should be *before* the front-controller, not at the end of the file. Otherwise, they are not going to execute for any request that is routed through your framework.

> when not in subdirectory having /vacancies -> /index.php/vacancies using this below .htcaccess file works

That's not actually what the above `.htaccess` code does. It should simply be rewriting the request to `/index.php`. (The frawework/Laravel then looks at the full URL that was requested.) If it rewrote the URL to `/index.php/vacancies` (that some frameworks do) then you would need to read the URL using *pathname information* (PATH_INFO).

> Though now the project exists within a subdirectory I require the URL to be re written as so `/vacancies` -> `/abc/index.php/vacancies`.

See above regarding the PATH_INFO. But if the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root of the site and the `/abc` subdirectory should be entirely hidden then you still have some work to do. You'll need to set the appropriate `RewriteBase` and modify the condition that removes the trailing slash off non-directories.

Otherwise, if the `/abc` directory is part of the URL then the `.htaccess` file can be moved to the `/abc` subdirectory, but you'll still need to modify the directives that remove the trailing slash.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input, I quickly realised the problems with        
`RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3` as this needs to be in the virtual host file and not here and `RewriteRule ^index.php [L]` needing to be `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`. Though I was unaware of the Authorisation Header problem, thats really helpful. I understand now that the htaccess rewrites to `/index.php` and the rest is handled by the framework. Thanks again